# namevaluecollection removes "+" characters from querystring

Tags: url, request, .net-4.5

I have the followigurl localhost.dev?q=dyYJDXWoTKjj9Za6Enzg4lB+NHJsrZQehfY1dqbU1fc= and extract the query string as follows:

```
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);

string str1 = query[0];
```

If i call query.ToString() it shows the correct characters query string. However, when I access the value from the NameValueCollection 'query[0]' the "+" is replaced by a empty " " i.e. dyYJDXWoTKjj9Za6Enzg4lB NHJsrZQehfY1dqbU1fc=

I've tried specifing different encoding and using the Get method from the namevaluecollection. I've also tried spliting the string, but the "+" is being removed each time. Has anyone got any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this chars in the url variables, you need use [URLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) and [URLDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy(v=vs.110).aspx) of HttpUtility class to convert this into a valid url.

I hope this help you.